# VFP List Button Object Fields

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, controller

Currently, converting a Javascript List Button to a List Button that uses a VisualForce Page.

The button is on a related list on the Opportunity layout.

Is it possible to grab Opportunity fields if the standard controller is a different object?

error: Unknown property 'OpportunityRequest__cStandardController.Opportunity'

```
<apex:page standardController="OpportunityRequest__c" recordSetVar="OpportunityRequests">

<script>
    if('{!Opportunity.Name}' != ''){
    parent.window.location='/apex/oppRequest?&oppId={!Opportunity.Id}'
    }
</script>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to get the data via the custom lookup field:

```
if({! NOT(ISBLANK(OpportunityRequest__c.Opportunity__r.Name)) }) {
```

I'd have to experiment a bit more to see what other changes you'd need to make, but this should help you get started.

Comment: The OpportunityRequest__c does not exist yet. If the Opportunity Name is not blank the user will be redirected to an apex page which has a form to create an OpportunityRequest.

Comment: @ebar It doesn't need to exist. The object name is a merge field used to represent the object in memory, which *should* already have the opportunity populated, if I'm remembering correctly.

Comment: So if I'm on an opportunity page and I click the button on the OpportunityRequest__c related list. And I alert('{!OpportunityRequest__c.Opportunity.Id}'); it will show the Id of the opportunity that im on?